# Posting corresponding datas on clicking submit button

Tags: php

```
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
{
?>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="sel_<php echo $i; ?>" id="sel_<php echo $i; ?>">
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
</select>
</td>

<td>
<input type="submit" name="sub_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="submit" />
</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Now I have 2 select boxes `sel_1` and `sel_2`, each of them have corresponding submit button `sub_1` and `sub_2`. I want to post the corresponding data when a submit button is pressed. For example: when I press `sub_1` I need to post the value of `sel_1`.

So, if press on the submit button in a specific row, I need to post the value of the select box in that row.

How can I do this?

Comment: There could be more than 2 select boxes???

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter that both select are sent. Just work with the one select you need.

```
if (isset($_POST['sub_0'])) {
    $data = $_POST['sel_0'];
} elseif (isset($_POST['sub_1'])) {
    $data = $_POST['sel_1'];
}
```

In `$data` will be value of the first, or the second one, select.

IF you need to send just one selectbox, you need more forms (each form will contain select and submit).

Answer (score 0):

since you have not mentioned the form method i am using `$_REQUEST` here,

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['sub_0'])) {
   // use the value of $_REQUEST['sel_0'];
} elseif (isset($_REQUEST['sub_1'])) {
    // use the value of  $_REQUEST['sel_1'];
}
```

**Note:** you can replace `$_REQUEST` with `$_POST` or `$_GET` as per you form method type or else you can use `$_REQUEST` itself if you wish to do so